# cast big number in human readable format

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm working with databricks on a notebook.

I have a column with numbers like this `103503119090884718216391506040`

They are in string format. I can print them and read them easily.

For debugging purpose I need to be able to read them. However I also need to be able to apply them `.sort()` method. Casting them as `IntegerType()` return null value, casting them as `double` make them unreadable.

How can I convert them in a human readable format but at the same time where `.sort()` would work? Do I need to create two separate columns?

Comment: What do you mean with 'human readable'? Something like: 103,503,119,090,884,718,216,391,506,040 ?

Comment: When I cast it in double I have something like this `1.03503119090884E+28`

Comment: Maybe `LongType` (instead of `IntegerType`) has sufficient digits?

Comment: Is this available for pyspark / databrick ? I'm not able to import it.

Comment: See the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.LongType.html

Comment: But for your value DecimalType seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the column sortable, you could convert your column to `DecimalType(precision, scale)` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.DecimalType.html#pyspark.sql.types.DecimalType). For this data type you can choose the possible value range the two arguments

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, types as T, functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(string_column='103503119090884718216391506040'),
    Row(string_column='103503119090884718216391506039'),
    Row(string_column='90'),
])

(
    df
    .withColumn('decimal_column', F.col('string_column').cast(T.DecimalType(30,0)))
    .sort('decimal_column')
    .show(truncate=False)
)
# Output
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|string_column                 |decimal_column                |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|90                            |90                            |
|103503119090884718216391506039|103503119090884718216391506039|
|103503119090884718216391506040|103503119090884718216391506040|
|103503119090884718216391506041|103503119090884718216391506041|
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Concerning "human readability" I'm not sure whether that helps, though.